# How to resolve DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, null, constraints

How to resolve this exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

I am facing this exception while deleting a record.

Comment: do you have any constraints ?

Comment: Examine the full stacktrace. It will tell which constraint is violated by the delete operation.

Comment: Yes, i have 3 constraints.
@manish: i have seen full stacktrace. and i have checked which constraint is violated. but still not able to getting. i have used one to one relationship. and also put the cascade to remove. but still not deleting the data and getting the same exception.

Comment: If you have database constraints that prevent a delete, there is no way around it. You can either ask your database administrator to remove the offending constraint if the constraint should not be there or modify the constraint to a `CASCADE` instead of a `RESTRICT` so that the delete cascades to the dependent tables as well if that is what is actually desired.

Comment: can i set that RESTRICT to CASCADE using hibernate ?

Comment: You can, but you would need to execute a DDL statement to do that. You really shouldn't do that as part of a running application due to the potential of corrupting the database. If your DBA is good, you will not be able to do either (the database user credentials used by an application should not allow it to run DDL statements). If you still insist on doing that, read the Hibernate documentation to find out more about running direct DDL statements.